# How can I connect Java on external DB?

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

i bouth db on sql205.bye*******.com, how can i connect java app on this db? for exemple:

```
Connection connection ;
PreparedStatement ps;

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql205.by********.com/b7_18206769_boh", "user", "pass");
 } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this don't work

Comment: Please google before posting questions here... basic examples are already available. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

Comment: this is for localhost, i know how to do with localhost

Comment: In the example sent by Sunil replace localhost with your url, sql205.by********.com/b7_18206769_boh and of course you need to modify the rest so it works with your database.

Comment: i modify localhost with  sql205.by********.com/b7_18206769_boh like my exemple but don't work

Answer (score 0):

"sql205.by********.com/b7_18206769_boh" is database_host/database_name.

Checklist:

- If server´s hostname is correct. Try it´s ip (ex. 10.0.0.3/dbname)
- Check if servers database has connection permission (you can try
  telnet sql205.by********.com 3306 or try do connect from app´s server
  shell)
- check if user has permission to access database from app´s
  host. (take a look at grant command on mysql - ex. grant all
  privileges on dbname.* to user@java_app_host identified by 'pass';)

Comment: Finally, tnks. U now if there are free hosting to test my db?

Comment: Why dont you test your project locally with Wamp (on Windows) or Mamp (on Mac) ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say ... with MAMP (or Wamp) you have MySQL and php with phpMyAdmin installed. So, you can easily test your projects.

Comment: but i create a sort of "chat" for more members, i need to test if other members see my message with other pc..

Comment: Your java app is for web with jsp and/or servlets ?